# Is there any way to print a widget by having its id?

Tags: widgets

I have a custom sidebar in wp created by:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'id' => 'test_w',
    'name' => 'test',
    'before_widget' => '<div class = "widgetizedArea">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
```

Now I print the IDs of the widgets inside with the code:

```
 $nomi_widget = array();
 $sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
 var_dump($sidebars_widgets['test_w']);
```

The output is:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'adni_widgets-93' (length=15)
  1 => string 'adni_widgets-96' (length=15)
```

The question is: is there a way to print widget in frontend using its ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to filter out all the other widgets in the sidebar while calling the `dynamic_sidebar` output.

**Updated to take widget index OR ID slug**

```
function custom_output_widget( $sidebar_id, $widget_id ) {
    global $custom_widget_target; 
    // if ( !$sidebar_id ) {
    //     $sidebars_widgets = get_option( 'sidebars_widgets' );
    //     print_r( $sidebars_widgets ); return;
    // }
    $custom_widget_target = array( 'sidebar' => $sidebar_id, 'widget' => $widget_id );
    add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'custom_widget_target_filter' );
    dynamic_sidebar( $sidebar_id );
    remove_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'custom_widget_target_filter' );
    unset( $custom_widget_target );
}

function custom_widget_target_filter( $sidebars ) {
    global $custom_widget_target;
    if ( isset( $custom_widget_target) ) {
        foreach ( $sidebars as $sidebar_id => $widgets ) {
            if ( ( count( $widgets ) > 0 ) && ( $sidebar_id == $custom_widget_target['sidebar'] ) ) {
                foreach ( $widgets as $i => $widget ) {
                    // echo '*' . $i . ' - ' . $widget . '*';
                    if ( ( $widget !== $custom_widget_target['widget'] ) && ( $i !== $custom_widget_target['widget'] ) ) {
                        unset( $widgets[$i] );
                    }
                }
            }
            $sidebars[$sidebar_id] = $widgets;
        }
    }
    return $sidebars;
}

// example based on widgets in original question
custom_output_widget( 'test_w', 'adni_widgets-93' );
```

**Updated and simplified with closure (takes widget slug:)**

```
function display_widget_wpse( $s_id, $w_id ) {
  add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', $callback = function( $widgets ) use ($s_id, $w_id) {
    return array ( $s_id => array_filter ( 
      $widgets[$s_id] ?? array(), 
      function ( $widget ) use ( $w_id ) { return $w_id === $widget; } 
     ) );
  } );
  dynamic_sidebar( $s_id );
  remove_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', $callback );
}
```

Comment: Continue to print all the widgets present in the custom sidebar and not the one I pass to the function ...

Comment: @PaoloBattiloro Try again with updated code, as it needed to match against array value of widgets instead of key.

Comment: nothing..same result :(

Comment: I like the filtering approach +1 and I updated the answer with closure to avoid globals.

Comment: @PaoloBattiloro if you just include the `var_dump` calls you have within the function itself, you should be able to debug yourself if things aren't matching up.

Comment: @birgire love your code, looks so elegant... totally different way of thinking, for the life of me cannot understand it lol

Comment: @majick I was blown away when my friend introduced me to functional programming, specifically [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). Hopefully I'm paying it forward :-)

Comment: now its work :) thanks a lot

Comment: @PaoloBattiloro yay! glad it worked out finaly. :-D
can you mark the answer as correct then.

Comment: sure, do you think there is a way to invoke widgets based on its position in the array?
like widget [0], widget [1] etc ... with a little update of your function? i wish to call with this hook: custom_output_widget( 'test_w', 'widget_array[0]' ); or something similar

Comment: sure just swap out the line `if ( $widget != $target_widget_id ) {` for `if ( $i != $target_widget_id ) {` instead and pass the widget index (number only) to the second argument.

Comment: @majick the first 2 function dont work for me so i have to modify second one : function display_widget_wpse. Can you please give the modify for this function instead? :)

Comment: i add this...i can see the right widget name but i not able to modify the rest of function....
 function display_widget_wpse($s_id, $w_id) {
        add_filter('sidebars_widgets', $callback = function ($widgets) use ($s_id, $w_id) {
    
            print_r($widgets[$s_id][1]);

Comment: @majick can you help me please? i need it

Comment: @PaoloBattiloro I updated my original functions to take either a widget ID (string) or index (number) and retested it works now. The second version I don't understand well enough to modify yet.

Comment: @majick i love you ! thanks :D :D